# Undefined Control Sequence using align*

Tags: errors, align, undefined

I'm trying to create a pdf of formulas for a class I'm taking. I have many code snippets as follows, one of which I've presented as a subset of my document below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{proof, environ, array}
\begin{document}

\section{Propositional Logic}

\subsection{Introduction of $\wedge$}
    \begin{align*}
      \infer[\rulename{\wedge_i}]
      {\alpha \wedge \beta}
      {\alpha && \beta}
    \end{align*}
    (If you have derived $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then you can conclude $\alpha \wedge \beta$.)
\end{document}
```

On every single instance of an equation formatted as above, I get an error on the `\end{align*}` line. The error is shown below:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \rulename 

l.21     \end{align*}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

For the most part, I have one equation per subsection, as above. If I have more than one equation per subsection, I get this error on all the `\end{align*}` commands within a subsection.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: It seems that `\rulename` is a rule specified by the professor whose equations I copied, but it is not defined within the source file I copied from. The effect I'm trying to achieve looks as follows: [image: Desired effect of my command]

Any tips as to how I can achieve this are appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\rulename` doesn't seem a command defined by the `proof` package. Where did you find it?

Comment: @egreg Thanks! The professor for this class has provided his slides in both pdf and LaTeX source for each individual slide. I basically lifted the align* section from his slides, and pasted it into a subsection with the proof library. I have no idea where `\rulename` comes from, despite my efforts to try and find out. I'd love to know, but I'm also open to alternatives.

Comment: Apparently your teacher has a definition for it, but it's impossible to guess at it without at least seeing the output.

Comment: take the latex source and add `\show\rulename` and tex will stop (as if for an error) and show you how `\rulename` is defined

Comment: @egreg I've modified the question to include a screenshot of the intended output of this command, if that helps you determine what the rule may do.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\rulename=undefined`, which I think may be the root of my problem.

Comment: I thought that you said that you could run the original slides?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The way I have the source is such that the preview of the slide is shown at the top of the page, with the source for that slide at the bottom (i.e. not a complete .tex file). I've also searched each of those slides for a `\rulename` declaration and unfortunately, cannot find anything. Bizarrely, there is no header for the source he has provided (the source begins with a `\begin{frame}` declaration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no definition of `\rulename` is provided, it's hard to guess. However, I can reproduce the output with a “dummy” definition for it, so it possibly is just for markup (and good for possible redefinitions).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{proof}

\newcommand{\rulename}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\section{Propositional Logic}

\subsection{Introduction of $\wedge$}
\begin{equation*}
 \infer[\rulename{\wedge_i}]
   {\alpha \wedge \beta}
   {\alpha && \beta}
\end{equation*}
(If you have derived $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then
you can conclude $\alpha \wedge \beta$.)

\end{document}
```

I have minimized the example; don't use `align*` as a surrogate for `equation*` when there is just one line.

[image]